# Riemann sum for a given function

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

So I have missed one of our lectures and I am finding it hard to understand how this works out with a split function, example below:

for $c_1 \neq c_2$ (constants)

$f(x) = \begin{cases} c_1  \space \text{if}  \space  0 \le x< 1 \\
         c_2   \space  \text{if}  \space  1 \le x\le 2 \end{cases}$

I need to calculate reimann sum for the Partition: 
$P = \{x_0=0,x_1=0.3,x_2=0.7,x_3=1.5,x_4=1.8,x_5=2\}$

and for these values:
$A.{w_1=0.2,w_2=0.5,w_3=0.9,w_4=1.7,w_5=1.9}$ and
$B.{w_1=0.2,w_2=0.5,w_3=1.4,w_4=1.7,w_5=1.9}$

---

Using the Reimann formula I came up with $1.5c_1+0.5c_2$ as a result for A but I am unsure of how should a splitted function be treated.

An explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A typo: Riemann sum, not "reimann sum".

Comment: @DietrichBurde You know you can also edit the question, right?

Comment: @5xum Maybe the OP should correct his own typos himself ?

Comment: @DietrichBurde I guess... but if you put in the effort to point out the typo, I don't see why you wouldn't just correct it. It would actually be quicker...

Comment: @5xum Quicker, yes, and more convenient for the OP yes. But will he learn it that way ? No.

Comment: Thanks, Will correct it. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The riemann sum, by definition, is

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} (x_{i+1}-x_i)\cdot w_{i+1}$$

In your case, this results in

$$(x_1-x_0)f(w_1) + (x_2-x_1)f(w_2) + (x_3-x_2)f(w_3) + (x_4-x_3)f(w_4) + (x_5-x_4)f(w_5) =\\
=0.3\cdot f(0.2) + 0.4\cdot f(0.5) + 0.8\cdot f(0.9) + 0.3\cdot f(1.7) + 0.2\cdot f(1.9)$$

Now just plug in the numbers and you get

$$0.3\cdot c_1+0.4\cdot c_1+0.8\cdot c_1 +0.3\cdot c_2+0.2\cdot c_2 = 1.5c_1+0.5c_2$$

so you are correct.

---

The Riemann sum **doesn't care** that the function is a "splitted function". The sum only cares about what the value of $f$ at the points $w_i$ is, and how long the intervals are. That's all. The value of $f\left(\frac1\pi\right)$ can be $23849234$, but that won't affect the riemann sum in question.

Comment: Thanks a lot. correct me if I am wrong but the method is basically a way of calculating the area between the function and the x coordinate, how, then, the area will accurately be calculated if the function is splited, in this case my concerns were by executing (x3-x2)*f(w3).

Comment: @Tom.A Each Riemann sum on its own is **not** the area between the function and the $x$ coordinate. The **limit** of the Riemann functions is the area.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I believe that makes the result for B. 0.7c1+1.3c2, since f(w3) = c2 in this case.

Comment: @Tom.A Exactly. remember, if this answer is what you were looking for, you can also upvote and/or accept it.

Comment: .if I want to prove integrability by definition between [0,2]? this seems odd, yet again I keep on having issues with the fact that it's splited.

Comment: @Tom.A First of all, that's a new question. Second of all, write down the definition of integrability. The **entire** definition. The one with $\epsilon$s

Comment: for all ε> 0, there exists δ such that for any partition P = p1,p2,...,pn (max_p<δ, and any points selected = w1,w2,....wn:  | Riemann sum - lim Riemmansum? | < ε

Comment: @Tom.A There you go. Now notice how the length of the integrals must be very small, so the integral covering the "splitting point" of the function will contribute very very little to the entire sum.

Comment: True thing, however when coming into the step of expressing both the Riemman sum (based on random partitions and calculating the Lim of Riemman sum, that remains unclear )

Comment: @Tom.A Yes, and that is also the topic of at least several hours worth of calculus lectures, so I don't know how you expect me to explain it to you. If you only missed one hour of lectures, you shouldn't be worried.

Comment: Alright, Thanks a lot for the help!